# PHP- \n does not work

Tags: php

when i try

```
echo "anything \n whatever";
```

the result :

```
anything

whatever
```

But when i try it from user input it doesn't work

test.php

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>Authentication v 0.04</h1>
    <form action="" method="GET">
     Login&nbsp;<br/>
     <input type="text" name="username" /><br/><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="connect" /><br/><br/>
    </form>
<fieldset><legend>Authentication log</legend><pre>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo $_GET['username'];


?>
</pre></fieldset></body></html>
```

if `$_GET['username'] = "anything \n whatever"`

the result is

```
"anything \n whatever"
```

it treats `\n` as string !!!

why ?

Comment: replace /n with <br> tag

Comment: If you enter `\n` in an input, that's the literal text that is sent. In source, it is an escape sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` is an escape sequence which represents an end of line [1]. An escape sequence only makes sense on PHP interpolation (i.e. double quotes).

In HTML `\n` has no special meaning so it is printed as a string. [2]

If there is an actual new line, you may want to use the `nl2br` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to automatically convert any `\n` to a `<br>` tag.

If you want to convert any literal `\n` to `<br>`, you may want to use a `str_replace` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for example like this:

```
echo str_replace ('\n', '<br>', $_GET['username']);
```

Notice the single quotes to avoid further interpolation.

[1] In fact, it is a new line only on *nix systems, while it's different on Microsoft and old Mac OSx. You may want to take a look at `PHP_EOL`constant (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

[2] In fact, it **is** printed as a new line in the HTML **source**, which is a text file.

Comment: very misleading. 1) "text file or with CLI input / output." - what? nope 2) nl2br won't fix his issue, there are no new lines here...

Comment: Yes they are. Assuming `$_GET['userinput']` is `"anything \n whatever"`, you can print it out and convert to HTML new lines with `echo nl2br($_GET['userinput'])`. There are lots of security issues here but it's not relevant to the OP question.

Comment: Think for example to `textarea` form elements, where `\n` chars are actually created as part of the value.

Comment: But in this case the input is `'anything \n whatever'` (mark the difference), so it won't work.

Comment: You are correct. Using a `\n` char in a `$_GET` value is not a newline and will not be converted by `nl2br`. On the other hand, a new line created by hitting the `return` key in a `textarea` input **is** a new line and **will** be converted.

Comment: So it really depends on where the input is coming from.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I edited my answer according to your correct observations.

Answer (score 1):

Escape sequences are only interpreted in double quoted strings in the PHP source (well, you can escape `\'` in single quoted strings, but that's not relevant here).

When you type `\n` in the browser, that's literally two characters, `\` and `n`.